# torch simply construct last output as previous layers' output multiply

Tags: lua, neural-network, torch, cudnn

My network have N layers, and I want the last layer simply construct last output as previous layers' output multiply like below. Suppose my the N-1 layer has a 3-d output, the last has a has a 2-d output. the last_output[1] = previous_output[1]*previous_output[2], last_output[2] = previous_output[3]. And I want to use a CrossEntropyCriterion on this 2-d last_output. Now I achieve this by construct the N-1 network model and get the last output as below:

```
local last_output = torch.ones(previous_output:size()[1], 2)
last_output[{{}, {1}}] = torch.cmul(previous_output[{{},{1}}], previous_output[{{},{2}}])
last_output[{{}, {2}}] = previous_output[{{}, {3}}]
```

So the last layer are not in the modle, and when simply run

```
loss = criterion:forward(last_output, target)
```

Error occur.
Is there any trick to achieve the purpose?

Comment: "error occur" is not very helpful. Please read [ask] and improve your post

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do that is to write a customized layer. See more from [torch developer docs](http://torch.ch/docs/developer-docs.html).